# Working with JSON-Objects in AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, json

I'm trying only to load **a part of a text file** (*.txt) into the HTML. The other part gives me more information about the amount of li's in it.
The text file contains a JSON-Object and looks like this:

```
{"content": [
        {"code": "<li><img src='images/einfamilienhaus.jpg' alt='' /></li>", "li": 1}
    ]
};
```

The Javascript code calling AJAX:

```
function loadSLD(number)
{
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    r = xmlhttp.responseText
    document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML=r.content[0].code;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","js/ajax/" + number + ".txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The code should now get *code* out of *content* and load it into the HTML, but it doesn't. I hope u guys can find the mistake I made. THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you expect it to parse the JSON for you?

```
r = JSON.parse (xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval function

```
    function loadSLD(number)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
           var response = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

        for(var i= 0; i<response.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML=response.content[i].code;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","js/ajax/" + number + ".txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
```